# How to center the survey form i created it

Tags: html

I attached a file in this, on this particular file called Rooms.html, there is a CSS connected as well, I'm trying to change things even though it's not working .... Anyone help me ... I'm hella struggling as well

Comment: give your email in private so i can send source file for your understanding

Comment: where is the file or image?

Comment: @ajai.s how to attach the file here? i can't see any options

Comment: you can attach image using the option available by default here

Comment: Please add html and css code as text with the code mark-up (three backticks). There is a good help text in the stackoverflow editor how to do this.